# Where to obtain boarding passes when travelling with distinct airlines?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, transit

I will be traveling from A to C, and I will have a connection at B.

For the A to B leg, I will be using airline 1, while for the second leg, B to C, I will be using airline 2. So, for the whole trip, I will travel with two different airlines.

The question is about the boarding pass from the leg B to C. At which airport can I take it? From airport A, the first airport, or do I get it at airport B?

I mean the second ticket, should I get it from the A airport?

Comment: @HaLaBi You actually understood the question??

Comment: @john I edited your question as I understand it. Did I understood correctly? You might want to be more specific about the airlines, because it may influence the answer.

Comment: Why is this not clear?  It's a perfectly valid question...

Comment: I just tried to improve the English to make it more understandable. I don't think I changed its meaning.

Comment: @doc the original version was very hard to make sense of (for some of us).  It's been edited since and makes a lot more sense, which is why it's got a couple of reopen votes.

Comment: In the current version, there is still something unclear: is it one booking or 2?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you bought the ticket.

- Many airlines have cooperation agreements which means that you buy a single ticket from A to C and get boarding passes for both legs when you check in at A. This also has the advantage that your baggage will be checked through and if you miss the connection because of a delay in the A-B flight, it is the airlines' responsibility to still get you to C without any additional cost to you.
- If there is no such agreement, or for some other reason you buy two separate tickets, then at B you have to collect your baggage and check in with airline 2 to get the B-C boarding pass. So you need a lot more time to make the transfer. And if you miss the connection, you have to pay for a new ticket.

Thus it should be clear that for the passenger it is pretty much always preferable to buy a single ticket. And in my experience it's always possible (But I've only travelled to places that are at least somewhat touristy).

Comment: This answer isn't correct.  There are 3 different concepts here (interline tickets, interline baggage, and boarding passes), and there is NOT a solid correlation between the 3.  For example, many times you can check through luggage (interline baggage) without being able to get a boarding pass - even on different tickets.

Comment: @Doc: OK, so it's simplified, but I'd still say it correctly answers the question, which is only about boarding passes. And being able to check through baggage on separate tickets is nice when it happens but not something you can rely on when planning your layover time.

Comment: I have two E-ticket now from two different Airlines ( both are member of Star Alliance ) so Can I take The real Ticket from first Airport ,I have hand bag only I don't Care about luggage . this is the Questions pals. thanks

Comment: @john: You can ask when you check in at the first airport, but it's almost certainly not possible to get the boarding pass for the second flight there. At least that's how I interpret the second answer here: http://www.staralliance.com/en/faqs/flight-and-baggage/ - so you'll have to check in again at the second airport. However, if you don't have checked luggage, you may be able to use online checkin or self-service machines to avoid waiting in queue with the people who have luggage to check in.

Answer (score 0):

The third situation is that you bought 2 tickets of different airlines in 1 reservation. It happened to me many times, especially when I travel International. From A-B, you take airline 1. But, because you will take airline 2 from B-C, the airline 1 won't give you a boarding pass for airline 2 (cos it's different airlines). However, the airline 1 will make sure that the baggage will go straight to C, so you don't have to pick up your baggage at B and check it in again. When you arrive at B, look for airline 2 counter to obtain a boarding pass. OR, sometimes the airline 2 arrives at International terminal already so you don't have to go out look for airline 2 check in counter and go through security again, instead you can check on the departure information board and find when the airline 2 with your destination gate is, and check with the airline 2 workers at the gate to obtain your airline 2 boarding pass. But it is always a good idea to make sure with the airline 2 that your baggage goes straight to C.